# c++ deleting all children in a tree structure while informing the parent

Tags: c++, list

Considering this:

```
class A {    
public:
     A()
    ~A()
     void add(A *child);
     void remove(A *child);
     void set_parent(A *parent);
private:
     A *parent;
     std::list<A*> children;
};
```

`add, remove` and `set_parent` do the obvious of accessing the list or the parent attribute.

With the following implementation:

```
A::A() : parent(nullptr){};
A::~A() {
    //Keep the hierarchy clean and inform parent that we are gone now
    if(this->parent != nullptr) {
        this->parent->remove(this);
    }
    //Also delete all children as they would be lost now ...
    for(A *child : children) {
        delete child;
    }
}
void A::set_parent(A *parent)
{
    if(this->parent != nullptr)
        this->parent->remove(this);
    this->parent = parent;
}
```

I actually do not want to do anything more complicated but the problem will be that when deleting the children of the list they each inform their parent that they are gone now, manipulating the list we are currently iterating over. What can one do?

Answer (score 2):

How about "detaching" the parent before deleting child?

```
A::~A() {
    //Keep the hierarchy clean and inform parent that we are gone now
    if(this->parent != nullptr) {
        this->parent->remove(this);
    }
    //Also delete all children as they would be lost now ...
    for(A *child : children) {
        child->set_parent(nullptr); // Detach parent to avoid re-calling remove()
        delete child;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not added this to the details but right now the set_parent also informs the current parent (if there is one) about the fact that the child changed it's owner

Comment: That's why you should put all the minimum relevant information in your question, you may get a sub-optimal answer otherwise. Anyway, it may still work if you have a way to "detach" that notification too . After all, you are destroying the child, there's no useful info in telling the parent that the child is changing parent (to nullptr, because it's detaching it).

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed it and for your "idea" I added a "if new_parent != nullptr" to the set_parent condition

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most straight-forward solution I can think is to simply have a boolean flag, that when set causes `remove` to simply do nothing. Set this flag before iterating over the list.

Then we have a solution that might actually be better: Smart pointers. Then you don't need the loop in the destructor at all, when the list object itself is destructed the contained pointers will simply "delete" themselves. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) are two good references you might want to study for this.

Then the best solution, IMO: To decouple the removal of elements from the destructor. Have an explicit function which removes the element from the parent, and don't have the `remove` call in the destructor. This, combined with shared pointers, is probably the safest way to handle it. Might require some redesigning (and possibly some refactoring) on your part though.

Answer (score 1):

With `std::list` it's easy to remove and iterate over it because an iterator is invalidated only when the corresponding element is deleted:

```
auto child = std::begin(children);

while(child != std::end(children))
{
   auto next = child + 1;

   delete *child;

   child = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by not iterating over the `list` in your destructor. Instead, delete children as long as there are still children.

```
A::~A() {
    //Keep the hierarchy clean and inform parent that we are gone now
    if(this->parent != nullptr) {
        this->parent->remove(this);
    }
    //Also delete all children as they would be lost now ...
    while(children.empty() == false)
    {
        delete children.back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
for (auto it = children.begin(); it != children.end();)
{
   (*it)->set_parent(nullptr)
   delete *it;
   it = children.erase(it);
}
```